# Is there a way to normalize rows in an fcm (i.e., transform counts into values from 0 to 1)?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, quanteda

Good day,

I have a feature co-location (fcm, from the quanteda package in R) of dimensions 94966 x 94966 (named fcm2, for illustration). I am able to select rows (class: fcm object) by the feature name or row number, e.g.:

```
a1 <- fcm2[1,]
```

and perform a normalization calculation on that particular row:

```
a2 <- a1/(max(a1)-min(a1))
```

My objective is to normalize each row in my original fcm. The strategy I attempted was to initialize an empty matrix and then use a for loop to go through the rows and perform the calculation. The initialization fails because of memory issues (Windows 10, 12 Gb RAM, R version 3.4.4):

```
fcm3 <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 94966, ncol = 94966)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 33.6 Gb
```

I had been able to accomplish the normalization by using a dataframe structure, but there is not enough memory to store the entire fcm2 as a dataframe:

Step 1: Extract a "sub-matrix" based on a list of keywords, convert to dataframe, drop unneeded columns

```
m <- fcm2[keywords(),]
df_m1 <- as.data.frame(m)
df_m1 <- subset(df_m1, select = -c(document, rt))
```

Step 2: Normalization

```
k <- 0 # initialize counter
df2 <- data.frame() # initialize
n4 <- nrow(df_m1) # count rows of the extracted sub-matrix as df (df_m1)

for(k in 1:n4){
  a1 <- df_m1[k,] # store the (n4)th row 
  max_k <- max(a1)
  min_k <- min(a1)
  a2 <- a1/(max_k-min_k) # normalize so max is 1, 0s are still 0s
  df2 <- rbind(df2, a2) # append normalized results into a row of a data.frame
 }
```

Is there a more efficient way to normalize each row for the entire fcm?

Kind thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yo can write a function:

```
norm=function(mat){
  mx=mat[cbind(1:nrow(mat),max.col(mat))]
  mn=mat[cbind(1:nrow(mat),max.col(-mat))]
  mat/(mx-mn)
}
```

And then use it.

Example

```
set.seed(1)
mat1=matrix(sample(20),5)
mat1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6   14    3    7  #max is 14, min is 3 thus divide by 11
[2,]    8   15    2   12
[3,]   11    9   20   17
[4,]   16   19   10   18
[5,]    4    1    5   13

norm(mat)
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.5454545 1.27272727 0.2727273 0.6363636
[2,] 0.6153846 1.15384615 0.1538462 0.9230769
[3,] 1.0000000 0.81818182 1.8181818 1.5454545
[4,] 1.7777778 2.11111111 1.1111111 2.0000000
[5,] 0.3333333 0.08333333 0.4166667 1.0833333
```

You can decide to print out in fraction form to see whether the results do represent what was needed:

```
MASS::fractions(norm(mat))
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
[1,]  6/11 14/11  3/11  7/11
[2,]  8/13 15/13  2/13 12/13
[3,]     1  9/11 20/11 17/11
[4,]  16/9  19/9  10/9     2
[5,]   1/3  1/12  5/12 13/12
```

Answer (score 0):

I can understand OP has constraint with memory, and he cannot allocate memory to hold another copy of that big `matrix`.

If memory permits then solution can be:

```
mat1 = t(apply(mat1, 1, function(x) x/(max(x)-min(x))))
```

With memory constraint, one can prefer to write a function to normalise a vector and apply it over all rows in `for-loop`. It should be an efficient way in given scenario.

```
# Function to normalize a vector
normalise <- function(x){
  x/(max(x)-min(x))
}

#Apply over all rows of matrix
for(i in 1:nrow(mat1)){
  mat1[i,] = normalise(mat1[i,])
}

mat1
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.5454545 1.27272727 0.2727273 0.6363636
# [2,] 0.6153846 1.15384615 0.1538462 0.9230769
# [3,] 1.0000000 0.81818182 1.8181818 1.5454545
# [4,] 1.7777778 2.11111111 1.1111111 2.0000000
# [5,] 0.3333333 0.08333333 0.4166667 1.0833333
```

**Data:** As used by @Onyambu

```
# Data
set.seed(1)
mat1=matrix(sample(20),5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **most efficient** way is to operate on the sparse values of the fcm object directly, avoiding any transformation into a dense object such as a matrix or data.frame.  This is how the dfm and fcm manipulation and computation functions are defined in **quanteda** and why these are able to executive quickly and within limited memory.

To define such a function for your type of normalisation, you could use the following function, which I have demonstrated here on a simple fcm.

```
library("quanteda")
library("Matrix")

myfcm <- fcm(data_char_sampletext, window = 5)
myfcm
## Feature co-occurrence matrix of: 244 by 244 features.
```

Now we define a function that (for convenience) transforms the fcm into a sparse triplet representation (the dgTMatrix class) and extracts the non-zero values using `split()`.  Each element of the resulting list will represent a row of your fcm, but only for non-zero values.  (Because of this, we also have to return a zero for empty rows.)

```
fcm_customnorm <- function(x) {
    x <- as(x, "dgTMatrix")
    split_x <- split(x@x, x@i)
    norm_x <- lapply(split_x, function(y) {
        result <- y/(max(y) - min(y))
        # transform any divisions by zero into zero
        result[is.nan(result)] <- 0
        result
    })
    x@x <- unlist(norm_x, use.names = FALSE)
    quanteda:::as.fcm(x)
}
```

Applying this on a subset, we see that it works:

```
myfcm[1:5, 1:5]
## Feature co-occurrence matrix of: 5 by 5 features.
## 5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "fcm"
##          features
## features  Instead we have  a Fine
##   Instead       0  5    1  4    1
##   we            0 10    5 20    5
##   have          0  0    0  4    1
##   a             0  0    0  6    4
##   Fine          0  0    0  0    0

fcm_customnorm(myfcm[1:5, 1:5])
## Feature co-occurrence matrix of: 5 by 5 features.
## 5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "fcm"
##          features
## features  Instead  we      have         a Fine
##   Instead       0 1.0 0.8000000 0.3333333 1.00
##   we            0 0.2 0.2000000 1.3333333 0.25
##   have          0 0   0.6666667 0.3333333 3.00
##   a             0 0   0         0.0000000 2.00
##   Fine          0 0   0         0         0.00
```

Another option would have been to extract the simple triplet representation to a data.table (from the **data.table** package) and then perform your computations using the grouping functions and `:=`.  But this approach is simpler and gets your desired result, which is a normalised fcm.

Comment: Thank you very much! As a note, I needed to update to quanteda v. 1.2.0 for as.fcm to work without errors.

Comment: Note also that the min(y) in the fcm_customnorm() function would have to be set to 0 to give the intended result, otherwise there can be values of Inf or greater than 1 contained in the normalized fcm.